# how to use lodash _ without operator with an array rather than multiple args

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I was expecting the lodash without function to take an array of values, but instead takes multiple args.  How do I pass it an array and make it work.

Example:

```
var bar = {
    foo: ['a', 'b', 'c']
};


_.without(bar.foo, 'c', 'a'); // works;
_.without(bar.foo, ['c', 'a']); // doesn't work
```

My exclusion list has to be passed in as an array or variable so it would be useful to know how to use an array with the without function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```js
var bar = {
    foo: ['a', 'b', 'c']
};


console.log(_.without.apply(_, [bar.foo].concat(['c', 'a'])));
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're in an environment where you can use the [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), `...`, then

```
.without(bar.foo, ...['c', 'a']);
```

Answer (score 13):

In this case, you can use the array of values as it is, with  [`_.difference`](https://lodash.com/docs#difference), like this

```
console.log(_.difference(bar.foo, ['a', 'c']));
[ 'b' ]
```

Comment: this is probably the better way to do what I need, but I accepeted Alexander's answer since it was specific to the exact question.  However, I'll be using your solution in my actual project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could use spread operator

```
var bar = {
    foo: ['a', 'b', 'c']
};

var arr = ['c', 'a'];

console.log(_.without([bar.foo], ...arr) ;
```

Comment: straight copy of a previous answer from 2 years ago: -1